# Postpone first observer until all other observers has been called in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an event observable which can have multiple observers.

The first observer is always a cleanup code that will dispose all other subscriptions to the observable (this is because all other observers can be added later by some other parts of the code).

```java
CompositeDisposable disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
Observable<Object> eventObservable = Observable.just(1);

disposable.add(eventObservable.subscribe(event -> {
    disposable.dispose();
    System.out.println("Observer 1");
}));

disposable.add(eventObservable.subscribe(event -> {
    System.out.println("Observer 2");
}));

disposable.add(eventObservable.subscribe(event -> {
    System.out.println("Observer 3");
}));
```

Current output:

```
Observer 1
```

Expected output:

```
Observer 2
Observer 3
Observer 1
```

One way to achieve this is to add `delay` for the first observer. But that does not seem like a proper way to do this.

Is it possible to properly ensure that the first observer is always called after other existing observers have been called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step a bit back; you don't need to handle manual disposing of all the intermediate stages.

```
Observable<Object> eventObservable = Observable.just(1).take(1).share();
```

This will automatically terminate after 1 event, and that will be distributed to all subscriptions to the `eventObservable`. No need for manual cleanup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I would still like to know if given the setup I provided it's possible to postpone the execution of the first observer. This is quite easy to do in RxJS due to a single thread and event loop, but have not found a way to do it in RxJS. I will accept your current answer if you don't think it's possible tho.

Comment: You cannot delay within the subscription handler, as that breaks the async guarantee of reactive streams.